# attribute error: 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'empty' for async await

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pytest, pytest-asyncio, asynctest

```
class a(self):
  async def x(self, p1, p2):
     await connection.fetch(p1)
     ....
     return df

  async def y(self, p3, p4):
     df = await self.x(x1, x2)
     if not df.empty:
       # code
```

How to write a test method for y()? After mock of x(), getting this error: `attribute error: 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'empty'`

`test_y.py:`

```
import asyncio 

def x_mock():
   ...
   return df

def test_y(mocker): 
   ...
   mocker.patch('a.x', return_value=x_mock())
   asyncio.run(y(p3, p4))
```

`x_mock()` is basically creating a dataframe

Comment: show your test code please

Comment: you’re not patching correctly, x is a function of a class so you should be using mocker.patch.object on the class instead

Comment: @gold_cy getting this error: `TypeError: object DataFrame can't be used in 'await' expression` in y()

Comment: that’s because you need to return an AsyncMock and by default a MagicMock is returned

Answer (score 0):

Following up from the comments, try using:

```
mocker.patch(..., new_callable=mocker.AsyncMock)
```